# Installation of pyethapp fails on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, installation, pyethereum, pyethapp

I'm trying to install pyethapp on Raspberry PI B+

`sudo pip install  pyethapp` getting error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
No local packages or download links found for pytest-runner>2.0,<3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-U_2TGJ/devp2p/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
    tests_require=test_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 245, in fetch_build_eggs
    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 821, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 833, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 294, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 602, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytest-runner>2.0,<3')
```

I already have `pytest-runner` installed :

```
$sudo pip install  pytest-runner==2.12.1
Successfully installed pytest-runner-2.12.1
$ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4096 Jan 15 20:33 pytest_runner-2.12.1.dist-info
$ sudo python --version
Python 2.7.3
$ sudo pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the official repo?

Try not using `sudo` when installing `pip` packages and also follow the official instruction for the installation: [pyethapp Github](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp#installation)

Comment: `sudo` used during installation you can see in from log

Comment: @Toren Did removing `sudo` fixed the issue?

Comment: No , but I paid attention that I had `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` . I have to avoid the mess somehow

Answer (score 0):

`pip install setuptools==37` made a trick